# SocketTimeoutException: New Spring Starter Project

Tags: spring, socket-timeout-exception

I have just started with Spring development, but i faced with an error when i tried to create a New Spring Starter Project; this error is about a time out connection, i am under a proxy so i established it in the STS but it did not work. I have tried to create this kind of project in STS and eclipse setting the same proxy configuration.

Any one of you know another solution?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you hit this URL in your browser? For me, `start.spring.io` resolves to, `104.17.46.2` which port 443 seems to be open on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing which solved my problem was the next.

- I only removed the "s" from "https", I could sound stupid and weird but I worked.

https://start.spring.io  <<<<----- It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is:

Step 1: just open the url https://start.spring.io/ and create your starter project according to your project requirement.

Step 2: Download the project file.

Step 3: import the project in to the IDE (I used Eclipse Spring Tool Suite).

Step 4: Update the project.

Worked for me.